# How to reduce space beetwen elements?

Tags: html

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to reduce the distance between the elements in the HTML? I want to, for example, text "Supporting Milestones" is written above table border and "Shutdown those on data center by end of 2017" above ul element?

Answer (score 1):

CSS margins for heading elements (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.) will have a default amount of top and bottom margin.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

You can change this in your CSS for those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS margins, by using a negative value.

```css
#header3 {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#header4 {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#header5 {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#header6 {
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>In this example Heading 1 and Heading 2 have the default margin values.</p>
<h1 id="header1">Heading 1</h1>
<h2 id="header2">Heading 2</h2>
<p>In this one Heading 3 and Heading 4 have the margin values set to zero.</p>
<h1 id="header3">Heading 3</h1>
<h2 id="header4">Heading 4</h2>
<p>In this one Heading 6's top margin value is set to -20px .</p>
<h1 id="header5">Heading 5</h1>
<h2 id="header6">Heading 6</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[try this css file to your html page](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css)

or change the margin and padding of te elements to 0